# Does not contain a definition for 'Show' and no extension method 'Show' error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to show an instance of PluginManagerView with the below code.

This XAML file is in the same namespace, same project. But I got an error at the line of `mainwindow.Show();` saying that

```
Error 1 'PluginManager.PluginManagerView' does not contain a definition for 'Show' and no extension method 'Show' accepting a first argument of type 'PluginManager.PluginManagerView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Blah procedyre .cs  30  24  PluginManager
```

Can anyone tell me about what the  problem is? And why doesn't it throw the error for the prior usages of MainWindow?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;

namespace PluginManager
{
    public class PublicProcedures : Application
    {
        public static void ShowPlugins()
        {
            var mainwindow = new PluginManagerView();

            //An aggregate catalog that combines multiple catalogs

            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            //Adds all the parts found in the same assembly as the Program class
            //catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(this.GetType().Assembly));
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog("./Plugins/"));

            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            var modules = container.GetExportedValues<IPlugin>();


            mainwindow.DataContext = modules;
            mainwindow.Show();
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call [Window.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx) (which i guess is what you want to do), PluginManagerView would have to be derived from class [Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590112), and its XAML would have to look somehow like this:

```
<Window x:Class="PluginManager.PluginManagerView" ...>
    ...
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining that whatever `PluginManagerView` is, it doesn't have a `Show` method (which you're trying to call in an instance of `PluginManagerView` called "mainwindow").