# Missing reference for wpf window? .Show() missing along with other display functions

Tags: c#, wpf, vsto, outlook-addin, windows-forms-designer

I am working on an Outlook 2016 VSTO plugin and I'd like to add a WPF window display functionality to a button. So now my code looks something like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows;


namespace TaskManager 
{
    public partial class RibbonTaskManager
    {
        
        private void RibbonTaskManager_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ButtonAddGroups_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            FormAddGroups formAddGroups = new FormAddGroups();
            formAddGroups.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that apparently formAddGroups does not contain a definition for "Show". I tried looking for possible missing references to no avail.
I added

> System.xaml
>
> WindowsFormsIntegration
>
> PresentationCore
>
> PresentationFramework

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609866/does-not-contain-a-definition-for-show-and-no-extension-method-show-error) thread, but the accepted answer solves a different problem, I think.

Comment: Looks like you've created a C# project (class or application) and not a WPF project

Comment: @LordWilmore: C# projects can absolutely hold WPF code.

Comment: Wait am I missing something? I added a new WPF User Control to my C# project and want to use it as if it was a Windows Form. Is that not possible?    ///Just seen SLaks response, nevermind. I guess the question is still open.

Comment: What is `FormAddGroups`? Is it actually a `Window`? What Build Action is its XAML set to?

Comment: Why did you make it a control if you wanted it to be a window?

Comment: FormAddGroups is a WPF User Control.

Comment: @Slaks yes I agree, but if you create a WPF project then it will automatically include those references for you

Comment: @BugFinder Well there's no other options in >Add New Item for me. Just WPF User Control. I thought it's basically the same thing.

Comment: You can't call Show() on a UserControl...

Comment: Well here's the problem - I thought UserControl was basically a WPF Window. Here we go, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `Show()` on a `UserControl` but could create a window and set its `Content` property to an instance of your `UserControl`:

```
var window = new System.Windows.Window();
window.Content = new FormAddGroups();
win.Show();
```